# Beginning commands

Tags: errors

I just started with TeXstudio and when I enter the simple commands that are

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Content
\end{document}
```

and save as PDF I still get the error seen on the picture.
[image: error i get]

Picture of commands in picture
[image: My commands]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is your viewer? Probably the .pdf is locked.

Comment: What do you see if you go to the "Log" tab?

Comment: TeXstudio is not enough. You also have to install the program and packages that do the real work, for example [TeX Live](http://tug.org/texlive/). Have you installed TeX Live?

Comment: I see nothing in "log" tab.  I tried to open it in other viewers but i can't still open it.

Comment: No I did not download that. Any other things to download?

Comment: Seem that you are using Ubuntu (or variant), you should install the texlive (and related) package. TexStudio is only an editor, it does not provide the LaTeX distribution.

Comment: first of all: TeXstudio is an editor. you need to make sure, you have the compiling engine installed as well, as already mentioned. second: you can't compile `*.pdf`-files. you need to save them with the extension `.tex`. these you then compile into PDFs.

Comment: I am watching tutorials on youtube but they don t tell me any thing you are saying. They install and open it everything works. After that I have saved the file with extention ".tex" but what am i to do in order to save as .pdf

Comment: You need to install TeX Live in order to create the PDF. You can either use packages provided by your distro (e.g. Ubuntu), if applicable, or you can use the installer provided by upstream. The former is probably easier right now. The latter is easier in the long run.

Comment: Ok I have downloaded the Tex Live and still get the same error it says that you need to save it with an extention what will i do after that?

Comment: check if your TeX Live distribution is installed properly by running `pdflatex document.tex` from bash. next see if TeXstudio is properly configured to call the compiler. GoTo `Options -> Configue TeXstudio -> Commands`. Best you post a screenshot by editing your question.

Comment: TexStudio proposes in its Help menu a "Check LaTeX installation" command, use it and report what it tells you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 1):

## Welcome to TeX.sx.

### First things first :)

- Be sure that Texlive is installed and that Texstudio recognizes the installation, check if it calls the compiler (pdflatex), do as @naphaneal and @DRi said;
- LaTeX is supposed to compile .tex files into .pdf files, so the document you edit is the source, and therefore must be saved with the .tex extension. When you run the command pdflatex upon it a .pdf file will be produced. And basically that's how TeX works.

### What next?

After compiling your simple first document you should take a look at the following documents that will explain how TeX and LaTeX work and show you very useful commands that will help you write more efficiently. The following books are good for beginners.

Geting started with LaTeX: http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/LaTeXPrimer/GSWLaTeX.pdf

The not so short introduction to LaTeX2e:
http://repositorios.cpai.unb.br/ctan/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf

And keep us posted!